# iCloud not sync using ad-hoc provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, provisioning-profile

My App is working fine in development environment (Developer provision profile) and syncs OK with other devices using iCloud.

When I use a Production certificate (for Ad-Hoc provisioning) the iCloud sync does not work anymore.

Any thing I have to check ? 
Are there differences in provisioning profiles from iCloud point of view ?

Thanks

Dario

Comment: Have you checked the ad hoc version creates the correct iCloud containers? Check developer.iCloud.com

Comment: Hi Duncan, using your link, the containers are correctly created with Developer provisioning, but are not created with the Production provisioning.

Comment: Can you run the ad hoc provisioning app on a development device and then check the logs on the device in Organiser to see what is in the logs?

Comment: Good idea! I'll test within few days. For the moment I wish you and your family, Merry Christmas and Happy new Year !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Ad Hoc provisioning doesn't work with iCloud.