# method [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize] return false

Tags: ios, objective-c

My ios app returns false for the method

```
[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize]
```

only in the simulator and non development devices. On my iphone, when i run via xcode, works fine and returns true.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore%5fclass/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5fref/occ/instm/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore/synchronize) says

> if an error occurred. For example, this method returns NO if an app was not built with the proper entitlement requests.

Here there is my entitlements file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I think my entitlements are fine. 
Any idea?

Here is the log of the simulator:

> Apr 14 10:07:48 mbpfrancesco syncdefaultsd[10209] : (Note ) it.zerbinatifrancesco.PriceRadar: client changed keys: pluto
>   Apr 14 10:07:48 mbpfrancesco syncdefaultsd[10209] : (Note ) Temporarily disabling global throttling for developement apps
>   Apr 14 10:07:48 mbpfrancesco syncdefaultsd[10209] : (Error) Error writing storage for it.zerbinatifrancesco.PriceRadar to /Users/Francesco/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/79050534-BDFD-4B6C-BAEA-8F9BFE545043/Library/SyncedPreferences/it.zerbinatifrancesco.PriceRadar.plist: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x364a520 {NSFilePath=/Users/Francesco/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/79050534-BDFD-4B6C-BAEA-8F9BFE545043/Library/SyncedPreferences, NSUnderlyingError=0x3652060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

EDIT: on testflight, with ad hoc profile, the synchronize succeed but the notification for NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification is not fired

Comment: Keep in mind, that You cannot test iCloud on simulator.

Comment: not true: with ios7 and xcode 5 it's possibile. Anyway it happens also with testflight and devices that are not registered in developer mode (but included in the ad hoc profile)

Comment: I am testing also with iOS 7 and xCode 5. It responds that iCloud is available, but I don't have NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore available

Comment: did you try with a non-development device? it's the same :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719618/icloud-not-sync-using-ad-hoc-provisioning-profile

Comment: nah, i think it works with ad hoc profiles. It's impossible that the only way to know if it works is sending the app to apple (anyway, i sent it a week ago, it wasn't working!). Never found in apple documentation this ;)